# Code blocks should be visually expandable, particularly for a mobile context

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, code-formatting, mobile-web

UPDATE: Expand Snippit already excists sometimes, that is totally what I want, but everywhere.

Also I notice that the code blocks are not horizontally scrollabe on chrome IOS, so I litterally can't see all the content on a block that is not scrollable.

---

Word wrap and the limited view on many mobile devices makes it difficult to read code particularly in a mobile context. I think having code blocks visually expandable would improve that experience.

[image: Button added to end of each code block.]

[image: Code is displayed full screen.]

Comment: not sure how a "toggle code fullscreen" button will help in anyway since in your second screenshot the text is still going off screen even without the left bar for the votes. unless you intend to force the mobile to rotate the screen. i would suggest maybe making the scroll bar a bit more obvious since when code block text goes outside the boundaries you see a scrollbar on desktop

Comment: OK I see this exists for code snippets. Really I just want that on every block within the mobile context

Comment: The bigger problem comes in larger code blocks where the content is truncated. I grant you it is only going to be useful in some places and where I to implement such a thing for real I would do my best to test for cases where it's actually useful, but that is a lot of places. Also I probably chose that screenshot poorly because it isn't actually a word wrap code block